# jQuery ajax deferred in javascript module

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to implement a helper javascript module that will make ajax calls.

Is this a proper way of implementing jQuery ajax promise ?

I know `$.ajax` returns already a promise, in this case does it make any sense of declaring a `dfd` variable as deferred, assign the $.ajax promise to it and return it? Is this ok or any simpler way of doing it?

```
window.my = window.my || {};
my = function() {
    'use strict';
    var makeCall = function(serviceUrl, object, headers) {
        var dfd = $.ajax({
            url: serviceUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(object),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: headers
        });
        return dfd.promise();
    };
    return {
        makeCall: makeCall
    };
}();
```

Comment: what is the need for `var dfd = $.Deferred();`... the value returned by `$.ajax()` itself is a promise so there is no need to call `dfd.promise()` agaib

Comment: I made the changes. So basically can I also say only: `return dfd;` inseatd of `return dfd.promise();` as the ajax returns a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is dynamically typed, you don't declare the variable as a type.

```
 var dfd = "wibble"; // string
 dfd = 56; // now it's a number

 dfd = $.ajax( /*etc*/); // now it's a reference to a Deferred object
```

Just remove your

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
```

it serves no purpose